# What's hook to use immediately after a user is authentcated

Tags: hooks, actions, authentication

Does anyone know the `add_action()` hook to use immediately after a user is successfully authenticated.

**Hook Test based on @mmm's answer**

I ran this test from my `mu-plugins.php` file:

```
function check_for_superAdmin() {
    if ( is_super_admin() ) { echo 'I\'m a Super Admin !'; exit; }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'check_for_superAdmin' );
```

the `check_for_superAdmin()` function works but the `is_super_admin()` function does not. I may need to pass a parameter in there. Checking....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

juste before testing login and password, you have the action `wp_authenticate`: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_authenticate

juste after test and only if logging is successful, the action `wp_login`: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login

and after logging, you can also modify the URL with the filter `login_redirect`: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

Comment: It did not work @mmm

Comment: maybe is it waiting for the working contract ?

Comment: Sorry @mmm, it actually does work. it is my `is_super_admin()` function that did not work.